# How to keep the HTML email signature fixed size?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-table

I have a problem with one email signature for. it is basically a table with boarders that aren't visible (to make it easier to align all the elements). It's 6 rows, 3 of them contain images, last one has some legal stuff (single cell per row). 2 rows are different: each has two cells (left and right). the problem is, when I send the email, it looks just fine in Outlook Web App, but in Outlook desktop app the two two-cell rows get crampped together to the left. I've tried to make it a fixed position and width, but I can't seem to be able to pull it off. Any suggestions, what do I do wrong?

```
<head>
</head>

<html>
<body>

    <table style="table-layout:fixed;margin-top:30px;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:30px;width:95%;border:0">
    <!--1-->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="table-layout:fixed">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="230">    
                            <p>
                                <span style="color:#eb0008; font-size:20px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif"><strong>%%displayname%%</strong></span><br />
                                <span style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif">%%title%%</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>

                        <td width="340" >
                            <p style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif">
                                <span style="color:#919191; font-size:13px;">mobile:</span> %%mobilenumber%%<br />
                                <span style="color:#919191; font-size:13px;">email:</span> %%email%%
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--2-->
        <tr>
            <td>

                <img style="margin:15px 0 8px 0" src="img" alt="linia" width="15" height="2" />

            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--3-->
        <tr>
            <td>

                <img style="margin:0 0 10px 0" src="img" alt="technic logo" width="160" height="47" />

            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--4-->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="table-layout:fixed">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="230px" overflow="hidden">
                            <p style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif">



                                Address1

                                <br /> Address1

                                <br /> Address1

                                <br /> Address1



                            </p>

                        </td>

                        <td width="340">



                            <p style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif;">

                                <span style="color:#919191;">nr telefonu:</span>number

                                <br />

                                <span style="color:#919191;">nr fax:</span>number

                                <br />

                                <span style="color:#919191;">del:</span>address

                                <br />

                                <span style="color:#919191;">www:</span> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif; text-decoration:none;">www.google.com</a>

                            </p>





                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--5-->    
        <tr>
            <td>

                <img style="margin:15px 0 8px 0" src="img" alt="linia" width="15" height="2" />

            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--6-->
        <tr>
            <td>



                <p style="padding:0;margin:0;  color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif">



                    LEGAL STUFF





                </p>



            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add screenshot for design of your table?

Comment: Hi Anmol

The screenshot is here:
https://imgur.com/a/2DxI2

I've been trying to do it multiple ways (that's why I've nested 2 tables in the first one, for those 2-cell rows). Here it is shown with extra borders.

Comment: Code looks good, there might be enclosing bracket issue, although i will update your code and post it,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few thing that can help you to create perfect emailer

1. Avoid margins, use `td` height attribute.
2. Avoid giving width in % , pixel is a better approach.

```html
<table style="width:600px;border:0" width="600" align="center">
    <!--1-->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="230">    
                            <p>
                                <span style="color:#eb0008; font-size:20px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif"><strong>%%displayname%%</strong></span><br />
                                <span style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif">%%title%%</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>

                        <td width="340" >
                            <p style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif">
                                <span style="color:#919191; font-size:13px;">mobile:</span> %%mobilenumber%%<br />
                                <span style="color:#919191; font-size:13px;">email:</span> %%email%%
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--2-->
        <tr>
            <td>

                <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                 <td height="15"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="linia" width="200"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td height="8"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--3-->
        <tr>
            <td>

                <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                 <td height="15"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="linia" width="200"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td height="8"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--4-->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table  style="width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="230px" overflow="hidden">
                            <p style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif"> Address1<br /> Address1<br /> Address1<br /> Address1</p>
                        </td>

                        <td width="340">
                        <p style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif;">

                                <span style="color:#919191;">nr telefonu:</span>number

                                <br />

                                <span style="color:#919191;">nr fax:</span>number

                                <br />

                                <span style="color:#919191;">del:</span>address

                                <br />

                                <span style="color:#919191;">www:</span> <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif; text-decoration:none;">www.google.com</a>

                            </p>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--5-->    
        <tr>
            <td>
              <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                 <td height="15"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="linia" width="200"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td height="8"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <!--6-->
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p style="padding:0;margin:0;  color:#1c1c1c; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif">LEGAL STUFF</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: seems to work for us. Altough the people approving in company didn't quite like added rows of blank space ;)

Comment: Yes, but for outlook we need to manage that because they don't accept margins and paddings